# In Apache Airflow, how do I set a script as a task?

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm trying to follow this tutorial

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html

Which has the following code

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located at:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep',
    bash_command='sleep 5',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

templated_command = """
    {% for i in range(5) %}
        echo "{{ ds }}"
        echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
        echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
    {% endfor %}
"""

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    bash_command=templated_command,
    params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in'},
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
t3.set_upstream(t1)
```

I have some python scripts (with args) which I am trying to set as tasks. I'm guessing I need to use the BashOperator somehow, but when I look it up, it doesn't really say how to set a script to it

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/operators/bash_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator

Comment: Could you show an example of a script you are trying to run?!

Comment: Have you tried to pass something like `"python my_script.py"` as a `bash_command`?